# why list of users are not shown in the django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

my goal is to show user list on the template in django. but it's not rendering the users.

accounts/models.py:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

accounts/admin.py:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['email', 'username', 'age', 'is_staff', ]
admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

accounts/form.py:

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('age',)
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserChangeForm.Meta.fields
```

accounts/views.py:

```
class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
class UsersView(TemplateView):
    template_name='homepage.html'
    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(UsersView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['object_list'] = CustomUser.objects.all()
        return context
```

and blogapp/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/',include('accounts.urls')),
    path('accounts/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='homepage.html'),name='homepage'),
]
```

templates/homepage.html:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Online users</h1>
<ul>
    {% for user in object_list %}
        <li class="user">{{ user }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock content %}
```

when i execute python manage.py runserver it is just showing the head line Online users but there is no list of users. i have created three users in admin but it is not showing anything in the template and there is no error. 
[image: no list in the template]

will you please help me on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution.

in blogapp/urls.py, i have to change this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('accounts.urls')), #here is the change...delete accounts/
    path('accounts/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='homepage.html'),name='homepage'),
]
```

after than i have to change some settings like LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL and LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL because they were redirecting the pages after login and logout. it took couple of full projects delete. i dun know why it is occurring but did my job. if someone knows, please mention.

thanx everyone